# How to use the number input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

I tried something like this code here, but it did not work and I'm completely clueless since I searched the web for answers and end did not find none. This is not the exact code I wrote but it's an idea of what I know so far, if anyone can help me I appreciate.

```
<body>
 <input type="number" id="j" step="1">
 <div id="a" style="position:absolute;background-color:black;width:100px;height:100px"></div>
 <script>
 var move=document.getElementById("a");
 var n = document.getElementById("j").value;
 move.style.left=n+++"px";
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen in here?

Comment: I want to move the div with the number input forward and backwards to be precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/SuCGg/5/) will answer your problem..

you have to put a `onchange="moveIt()" onkeyup="moveIt()"` on your `input` tag for the div to know that it has
to move everytime you enter new values.

for example :

```
 <input type="number" id="j" step="1" onchange="moveIt()" onkeyup="moveIt()"/>
```

and on javascript :

```
function moveIt(){
 var move=document.getElementById("a");
 var n = document.getElementById("j").value;
 move.style.left=n+++"px";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ejay, onkeyup only works if they type a number in the input, I've modified your code and this works better

```
   <input type="number" id="j" step="1" onchange="moveIt()" onkeyup="moveIt()" />

   function moveIt(){
      var move=document.getElementById("a");
      var n = document.getElementById("j").value;
      move.style.left=n+++"px";
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SuCGg/2/